# Is this a proof of the density ($x < a < y$) of the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I want to prove that there exists a rational number between any two real numbers or that the rationals are everywhere dense in the set of reals. I'm taking the set of reals to be an Archimedean ordered field, and by the Archimedean axiom$^{1}$ it is true that for some real number $x$, and positive integers $n,~k$ that $k{1 \over n} > x$, and if there exists a real number $y$ such that $y > x$, then we could say that $y = k{1 + n \over n}$, and therefore $x < k{1 \over n} <  y$, and therefore there exists a rational between (positive) reals. The case for $0$ is trivial as there exists a real $x$ and $y$ such that $x < 0 < y$, and for the negative reals we say that for $0 \geq y > x$, then $0 \leq -y < -x$ and so our previous proof for the positives apply, and therefore there exists a negative rational too.
Edit: I realize that I made a mistake by saying $y$ is only equal to $k{{1+n} \over n}$. It should be the case that $y \geq k{1 \over n}$ otherwise $y$ wouldn't be greater than $x$ as $x < k{1 \over n}$. We could still set $y$ such that $y \geq k{1 \over n}$ by necessity, and continue with the proof normally. (Check the comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4237182/956717)

---

1: It states that for every real number there exists positive integer which is greater than the real. I.e. $n > x$, which implies that $ny > x$, for some positive $y$ if we replace $x$ by $x \over y$, and if we also replace $x$ in $n > x$ with $1/b$ for some positive $b$ then $x > {1 \over n}$.
I looked at the proof in my book and it seemed very lengthy, and so I thought of a way to shorten it but I'm doubting myself, and I need external validation on whether it is correct or not.
I hope the question wasn't unproductive or the proof isn't embarrassingly wrong. Thanks for helping! (If the answer is correct, please do comment so!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is to be proven that set of rationals $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, you need to prove that given **any** real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x\lt y$, there must be a rational $q\in \mathbb Q$ such that $x\lt q\lt y$.

In your proof, you have arbitrary $x$ but then you chose $y$ such that it is greater than $\frac kn$. This restricts the arbitrary nature of $y$ therefore the proof needs work there.

Alternatively, you could proceed like this:

Let $x\lt y$ be **any** given real numbers.
Hence, $y-x\gt 0$. It follows by Archimedean property that there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n(y-x)\gt 1\implies ny\gt nx+1$

It follows by the property of floor functions that $\lfloor nx\rfloor\le nx\lt \lfloor nx\rfloor+1\le nx+1\lt ny$, where $\lfloor \rfloor$ is floor function.

It follows that $nx\lt \lfloor nx \rfloor+1\lt ny\implies x\lt \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor+1}{n} \lt y$.

Comment: $y$ has to be greater than $k \over n$ for it to confine to the Archimedean axiom as $x > {k \over n}$ by the axiom (check footnote). I like the patch done at the end. One question though, why do we need to floor $nx$?

Comment: @Math3147: The problem is with "if there exists a real number $y$ such that...could say that $y=\frac {k(1+n)}n$". Note that here you are assuming $y$ to be rational. But you want to prove "for any $x$ and $y$". Use of floor $nx$ here is Well ordering principal in disguise (try proving for any real numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p-q\gt 1$, there must exist an integer $n$ between $q$ and $p$). That's why I brought arbitrary $x$ and $y$ into that form (note $ny-nx\gt 1$).

Comment: I acknowledge that, and I think you're correct. I'm saying that if $y \geq {k \over n}$ without saying $y = k{{1+n} \over n}$, then shouldn't that made it real as it must be greater than or equal to ${k \over n}$ or otherwise it would be smaller than $x$ which is a contradiction? Shouldn't that fix it or... ? :(

Comment: @Math3147: You are again restricting $y$ when you say "if $y\ge \frac kn$" and you're not supposed to do that (What if $y\lt \frac kn$?). Please note the first two lines of this answer wherein I have bolded "any".

Comment: > and if there exists a real number y such that y>x
The proof assumes (to begin with) it because otherwise, by the Archimedean axiom, $x > k{1 \over n}$ which would imply that $x > y$.

Comment: @Math3147: You can't just assume $y$. As I stated earlier, $y$ is **arbitrary**. Why would $x\gt \frac kn$ imply that $x\gt y$? What if $y\gt x$ or what if $y\lt \frac kn$? (It can be done as $y$ is arbitrary!)

Comment: "therefore there exists a rational between (**positive**) reals. The case for $0$ is trivial as there exists a real $x$ and $y$ such that $x<0<y$, and for the negative reals we say that for $0 \geq y > x$, then $0\leq −y < −x$ and so our previous proof for the positives apply, and therefore there exists a negative rational too."
I go on to address when $x > y$, and also the zeroth case. If what we proved is true about the positive case where $y > x$, then for the negative ($x > y$) case it is, and therefore it is arbitrary.

Comment: @Math3147: You have not answered my question in my earlier comment. Let's first consider only positive real numbers (excluding $0$). You have $x$ and by Archimedean property you have an $n$ such that $x\lt \frac kn$ (here as per you, $k$ is a positive integer. But what is it exactly?). Then $y\ge \frac kn$ (you chose $y$ here like this and that this is not really an implication of $x\lt \frac kn$ ). But what if $y\lt \frac kn$?

Comment: It wouldn't be greater than $x$?

Comment: @Math3147: It may or may not. Why don't you take some values of $k,x$ etc. to verify that?

Comment: I didn't realise that in the moment. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Math3147: It's no problem. Glad you figured that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given $x$, you found positive integers, $k$ and $n$. You then let $y = k\cdot \frac{1+n}{n}$. You are not suppose to choose $y$.

You are given $x$ and $y$ and you are suppose to find $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies $x < a<y$.

Furthermore, if $y = k\cdot \frac{1+n}{n}$ where $k$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ but in general, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, it need not be a rational number.

Comment: I see but can't we also say that for any number added? So is simple $y > k{1 \over n} + a$, such that $a$ is a positive real? Wouldn't it still hold then... because regardless that has to be the case... right? Or am I missing something? :(

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by number added. We have $\frac{k}n$ that is promised to be bigger than $x$. How do you find your $a$?, we want $a$ to be a rational number and not just real right.

Comment: I didn't mean the $a$ as you defined it, sorry. I meant some arbitrary $a$ which is real. You said that I set $y$ which goes against it being arbitrary, and then I said $y > k{1\over n} + a$ for some arbitrary real number $a$. It has to satisfy that because of the Archimedean axiom as $k{1 \over n} > x$, then it cannot be the case that if $y > x$ that $y > k{1 \over n}$, and therefore $y > k{1 \over n}$ which means it is equal to $k{1 \over n} + a$ for some arbitrary positive $a$. Does that fix the problem with no choosing $y$?

Comment: Therefore we could say $x < k{1 \over n} < k{1 \over n} + a$, which means $x < k{1 \over n} < y$. Therefore the proof is fixed? Also, fixes the problem with it being exclusively rational as $a$ is now a positive real?

Comment: Let $x = 2$ and $y=3$. If we pick $k=5$ and $n=2$, then we are good. I don't quite follow how you ensure that $\frac{k}{n}  < y = 3$ in this case. What if $k=10$ and $n=2$? ( I know you can choose it but it is not clear from the current procedure how do you pick it.)

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making sense. The proof said first that $y > x$, then by the axiom, $x$ must be less than $k{1 \over n}$ (check footnote in the question). If we said $y$ is less than $k \over n$ then we've a contradiction due to $y > x$.

Comment: I am confused, $x$ must be less than $\frac{k}{n}$ right? btw, I'll be away for a few hours.

Comment: Less than*, yes sorry. Misspoke. Also, just fine! Thanks for helping me out anyway. :)